# is it acceptable to update a question with content added in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, questions

Sometimes when a new user post a question and the other users ask him to provide more details, explain clearly his use case or provide a specific code, he will provide that in comments with a bad format mostly a code snippet, and he would be asked to provide that in question body, however he doesn't do that, after this he could be answered and leaves the stack without updating his question, so could we edit his question by the comments content appropriately?

Comment: Yes, that is explicitly the goal of editing, either by the OP or visitors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, comments are meant as [*temporary*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) notes to the question. Any information in there which is necessary to answer the question should be in the question itself.

I'd update the question *and* post another comment making the OP aware of this policy, so that they'll update their question by themselves in the future.

Since the comment is also part of the Stack Exchange Q&A content, it's also *legal* to do this; there are rare cases where the OP includes a link to their code and the linked website doesn't allow copying the code into Stack Exchange. In that case, the OP has to do this themselves, or risk the question being closed because it's unclear, or (specifically to Stack Overflow) is lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).